# VBScript and concatenation of variable

Tags: vbscript, concatenation

I do not want to use arrays but want to concanate variable in order to devide some variables with one loop for example something like this:

```
Dim varr1,varr2,varr3,varr4,i
i=1
varr1=2
varr2=5
varr3=8
varr4=9
Do While i < 5
  varr&i = (varr&i)/2
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Could this be done in any way?

Comment: Even if it can be done: don't. It's a terrible practice with no redeeming qualities. Use an array or a dictionary instead. DO NOT construct variable names dynamically. EVER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [Execute](https://ss64.com/vb/execute.html) command to get what you need.

```
Dim varr1,varr2,varr3,varr4,i
i=1
varr1=2
varr2=5
varr3=8
varr4=9
Do While i < 5
  Execute "varr"&i&" = (varr"&i&")/2"
  'Execute "MsgBox varr"&i                                'un-comment this line to see the desired output
  i = i + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim concat
concat = varr1&varr2&varr3&varr4
```

You cannot automatically iterate through each of these variables unless you store them in an array.

Comment: We can do it using Execute statement.